# how to convert java class encoding to utf-8

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, maven-2

i'm working on a java project and i have a package that contains many clasees (more than 100 files) some files are not saved with utf-8 and this cause some problem in the compilation proccess..

my question is : there is a way to change the encoding for theses all classes to utf-8 at once , somethink like bach script.. ? i'm using windows.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds more like a batch/powershell question than a java question.

Comment: the JDK includes the [native2ascii](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/native2ascii.html) tool. Use `-encoding UTF-8`. I did it once using find command in the bash shell that comes with GIT...